# React useImerativeHandle does not update value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[See codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/impertive-handle-test-v2-rzhv1?file=/src/index.js)

I am trying to pass the state value of a child component up to its parent by using React's `useImperativeHandle`. However, it appears that my parent component is not receiving the updated state value of the child component when it console logs the child's component value; `console.log(componentRef.current.state)` always is logged as false.

Why is this not working and how can I accurately receive the mutated state value of my child component in my parent component by passing the necessary ref? Thanks!

**index.tsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Component = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [state, set] = React.useState(false);

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    state
  }));

  const handleClick = () => {
    set(prevState => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
      <h1>{state ? "On" : "Off"}</h1>
    </>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const componentRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(componentRef.current.state);
  }, [componentRef]);

  return <Component ref={componentRef} />;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want that functionality you can use something like:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Component = props => {
  const [state, set] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => props.callback(state), [state])

  const handleClick = () => {
    set(prevState => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
      <h1 >{state ? "On" : "Off"}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {

  return <Component callback={val => console.log(val)} />;
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

But if you really need to use `ref`, just comment it so I'll remove this answer.

Comment: thanks @StackedQ, added a question related to your implementation suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62986621/invoking-a-function-from-a-child-component-in-a-parent-component-via-callback)