# Invoking a function from a child component in a parent component via callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[See codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-callback-debug-k4fys)

I want to use a callback in a child react component so that I can invoke a function from my child component in my parent component. However, when I handle the callback in my parent component, and try to set this child's function so that I can invoke this function later on when a button gets clicked, this function ends up getting invoked unexpectedly.

What I want to happen is that the `sampleFunction` to be invoked when the 'Invoke Sample Function' button is clicked, but instead, `sampleFunction` is invoked when the parent component is mounted (and the console is thus logged with 'foo'). How can I properly pass this callback function from the child to the parent? Thanks.

**index.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Component = ({ callback }) => {
  const [toggleStatus, setToggleStatus] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    callback({
      toggleStatus,
      sampleFunction: () => console.log("foo")
    });
  }, [callback, toggleStatus]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setToggleStatus(prevState => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
      <h1>{toggleStatus ? "On" : "Off"}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [fn, setFn] = React.useState(null);

  const handleCallback = props => {
    setFn(props.sampleFunction);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Component callback={handleCallback} />
      <button type="button" onClick={fn}>
        Invoke Sample Function
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it possible to React.useState(() => {}) in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621212/is-it-possible-to-react-usestate-in-react)

Comment: I'm curious how this will work though, as when you call `setFn()`, `<App />` will re-render causing `<Component />` to re-render and re-invoke `handleCallback` in an endless loop, unless I am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-callback-debug-v2-m10l4?file=/src/index.js)

Thanks to @StackedQ and @Anthony for the help. As Anthony mentioned, in order to avoid an endless loop, I had to add an extra condition to `handleCallback`:

**index.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Component = ({ callback }) => {
  const [toggleStatus, setToggleStatus] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    callback({
      toggleStatus,
      sampleFunction: () => () => setToggleStatus(prevState => !prevState)
    });
  }, [callback, toggleStatus]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setToggleStatus(prevState => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
      <h1>{toggleStatus ? "On" : "Off"}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [fn, setFn] = React.useState(null);

  const handleCallback = props => {
    if (!fn) {
      setFn(props.sampleFunction);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Component callback={handleCallback} />
      <button type="button" onClick={fn}>
        Invoke Sample Function
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621212/is-it-possible-to-react-usestate-in-react) covers and the usage you want, you should use `useCallback` ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) - [more info](https://nikgrozev.com/2019/04/07/reacts-usecallback-and-usememo-hooks-by-example/)) instead of `useEffect`. something like the following is kind of better implementation:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Component = ({ callback }) => {
  const [toggleStatus, setToggleStatus] = React.useState(false);


  const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setToggleStatus(prevState => !prevState);
    callback({
      toggleStatus,
      sampleFunction: () => () => console.log("foo")
    })
}, [callback, toggleStatus])


  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
      <h1>{toggleStatus ? "On" : "Off"}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [fn, setFn] = React.useState(() => null);

  const handleCallback = props => {
    console.log(props)
    setFn(props.sampleFunction);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Component callback={handleCallback} />
      <button type="button" onClick={fn}>
        Invoke Sample Function
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: this functions differently to the OP - the callback was setting the function after render versus on click of the button as in your example

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code as you are calling the callback in the initialization of your child component.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // remove below call
    callback({
      toggleStatus,
      sampleFunction: () => console.log("foo")
    });
  }, [callback, toggleStatus]);
```